# Master Detail Application - Static Table in Detail View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to code an app in Xcode 4, with storyboarding. It's a master detail application, and it all worked fine, with the table and the detail view. But in my detail view, I would like to have a static table to display the data. In a grouped table style way, with the "key" on the left and "value" on the right, if that's a way to put it... So, it's all working fine until I put a table into my UIView. Apparently you have to put it in a UITableView for it to work, so I deleted the UIView that Xcode made for me and put in a UITableView in its place. I set it up EXACTLY the same (I think) with the identifier, title etc... and then connect the table cells up with outlets and what not. But now when I enter the view, I just get an empty table (well, not empty, just all the rows say "Detail" in rather than the actual data I want). I don't see why! D: I even changed DetailViewController.h to say "UITableViewController" as well! No avail... :( Could someone please enlighten me as to what I'm doing wrong! I bet it's really simple... :L Here's my code

MasterViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class DetailViewController;

@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) DetailViewController *detailViewController;
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *verbs;

@end
```

MasterViewController.m

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "VerbData.h"

@interface MasterViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *_objects;
}
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

@synthesize verbs = _verbs;

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
        self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);
    }
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)  [[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
    self.title = @"Verbs";
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    if (!_objects) {
        _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [_objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _verbs.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"VerbCell"];

    VerbData *verb = [self.verbs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = verb.infinitive;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = verb.english;
    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [_objects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        VerbData *object = [self.verbs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        self.detailViewController.detailItem = object;
    }
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        VerbData *object = [self.verbs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
    }
}

@end
```

DetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "VerbData.h"

@interface DetailViewController : UITableViewController <UISplitViewControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) VerbData *detailItem;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *detailDescriptionLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *jeOutlet;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *tuOutlet;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ilOutlet;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nousOutlet;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *vousOutlet;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ilsOutlet;

@end
```

DetailViewController.m

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *masterPopoverController;
- (void)configureView;
@end

@implementation DetailViewController

#pragma mark - Managing the detail item
@synthesize detailItem = _detailItem;
@synthesize jeOutlet = _jeOutlet;
@synthesize tuOutlet = _tuOutlet;
@synthesize ilOutlet = _ilOutlet;
@synthesize nousOutlet = _nousOutlet;
@synthesize vousOutlet = _vousOutlet;
@synthesize ilsOutlet = _ilsOutlet;

- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }

    if (self.masterPopoverController != nil) {
        [self.masterPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.

    if (self.detailItem) {
        self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = self.detailItem.english;
        self.jeOutlet.text = self.detailItem.je;
        self.tuOutlet.text = self.detailItem.tu;
        self.ilOutlet.text = self.detailItem.il;
        self.nousOutlet.text = self.detailItem.nous;
        self.vousOutlet.text = self.detailItem.vous;
        self.ilsOutlet.text = self.detailItem.ils;
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.title = self.detailItem.infinitive;
    [self configureView];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setJeOutlet:nil];
    [self setTuOutlet:nil];
    [self setIlOutlet:nil];
    [self setNousOutlet:nil];
    [self setVousOutlet:nil];
    [self setIlsOutlet:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}

#pragma mark - Split view

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    barButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Master", @"Master");
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem animated:YES];
    self.masterPopoverController = popoverController;
}

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
{
    // Called when the view is shown again in the split view, invalidating the button and popover controller.
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];
    self.masterPopoverController = nil;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing I will try to debug is *-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath* method. Is it return values? Try to put NSLog in this method and check it.

Or maybe this will help you:

> Note: If you want to change the background color of a cell (by setting the background color of a cell via the backgroundColor property declared by UIView) you must do it in the tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: method of the delegate and not in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: of the data source. Changes to the background colors of cells in a group-style table view has an effect in iOS 3.0 that is different than previous versions of the operating system. It now affects the area inside the rounded rectangle instead of the area outside of it.

Comment: I don't think it's being called...?

Comment: why? its a delegate method which is called when you display UITableView

Comment: Er, well maybe it is then... :| I slapped this in that method: "NSLog(@"%@", self.detailViewController);" and nothing got output. Is that the right way to use NSLog? I'm thinking no...

Comment: Just done NSLog on the viewDidLoad in DetailViewController to see what detailItem is set to. It's null. Any idea why this could be? :/

Comment: Oh and it is being called :L I put it in an if statement by mistake, that is obviously returning false

Answer (score 0):

The code must handle the case where dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier answers nil...

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"VerbCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

Comment: Sorry to hear.  I might be missing your question - you have moved the table to your detail view?  The code posted shows it in the master view.  You want the table to be static?  The code posted shows logic for dynamic content.  Do you have a fixed number of items?  The code still implements numberOfRowsInSection and numberOfSections - these might actually keep your static table from working.

Comment: No, the master view contains a table listing verbs. The detail view must contain a static table with 6 rows. je, tu, il/elle, nous, vous and ils/elles. Each of has something to show on the right, a right detail cell. :)

Comment: Which one isn't showing up (dynamic on master or static on detail)?  Also, you probably did this, but did you make sure datasource is setup for both?

Comment: Static on detail isn't showing up, and yes datasource and delegate are set up for both tables...

Comment: Can you post this project somewhere I can see it?  I'm not sure what you've got those label outlets hooked up to.  The way I setup static table content is to access the cells by calling cell = [myTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];  (setup an indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]; etc.  Then I touch cell.textLabel.text = @"hello world";

Comment: Ermmm. Where could I upload it to? I could put it in a tar file or something and put it on mediafire. I'll do it when I get home this evening (:

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16789/discussion-between-bradley-neil-reed-and-danh)